# Node.js: Async function seems to not wait for resolve of Promise within for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise

For loop ends without any code after the first `await new Promise` being executed. If I understand correctly, each iteration should pause for 2 seconds before `Promise` is resolved, `console.log` ouputs the specified string, and the iteration ends. How should I rewrite the code to make it work as I intended?

```
'use strict';

(async function () {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        await new Promise(resolve => { setTimeout(() => { resolve }, 2000) });
        console.log('end of loop');
    }
})();
```

Comment: Voting to close. The problem was caused by a typo. **You forgot the `()` needed to *call* the `resolve` function**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to call resolve function in your setInterval callback.

```
await new Promise(resolve => { setTimeout(() => { resolve() }, 2000) });
```

Comment: setInterval -> setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

In your snippet `setTimeout` will call anonymous function that will evaluate `resolve` as expression, which return a function. You need to call `resolve()` explicitly or pass it to `setTimeout` as first argument of type `function`.

Change

```
setTimeout(() => { resolve }, 2000)
```

to

```
setTimeout(resolve, 2000)
```

or

```
setTimeout(() => { resolve() }, 2000)
```

Comment: @Milan `setTimeout` calls first argument (function) after timeout, you can also specify arguments like `setTimeout(resolve, 2000, "promise will be resolved with this string")`

Comment: In either case it seems that OP either didnt know it was function that needed to be called or just made a type. This whole questions and answers thread doesn't add much to the Stack overflow community as Quentin suggested this should be closed.

Comment: @Milan Agree with you

Answer (score 0):

You can write this way,

```
'use strict';

var wait2Sec = function (time = 2000) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(() => { 
            resolve(); // <--- remamber to call the resolve function
        }, time)
    });
}

(async function () {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        await wait2Sec();
        console.log('end of loop');
    }
})();
```